# Bitmap, graphic and display byte[] as image - after redraw img going be darker

Tags: c#, .net

it may be strange, but the problem is real.
This is source code:

```
    public byte[] getBytes(int type, int color)
    {
        Bitmap bit = Art.GetStatic(type);

        if(color != 0) RedrawHue.RecolorFull(hues[color], bit);

        Bitmap newbit = new Bitmap(bit.Width, bit.Height);

        Graphics newgraph = Graphics.FromImage(newbit);

        newgraph.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0);

        this.forImgPictureBox.Image = newbit;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        newbit.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] res = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Dispose();

        return res;

    }
```

It doesn't matter what GetStatic and Recolor function do, but the problem is that after using this function more and more times- my img going be more and more darker... It's not joke- first time it's light, after 3 times there is a little grey, after 7 times it's all black.

What's going on? o.O

If i make breakpoing after this row:

```
Bitmap newbit = new Bitmap(bit.Width, bit.Height);
```

VS shows me, that newbit everytime changes, but bit not.

Comment: Well, if `it doesn't matter what GetStatic and Recolor do`, what happens when you remove the calls to these?

Comment: I mean, that this functions get bytes of image from big file.

Comment: Folks who down voted this question, I get it--it wasn't asked perfectly, but try to account for the fact that English might not be the OP's original language.  A little thought about what the OP was *trying* to ask, led me to the answer below and it may have helped them.  Then again, if the OP was constantly downvoted without comment, he/she may not have incentive to come back and find the help they needed in the first place.  Isn't helping each other the point of this place?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this line:

```
if(color != 0) RedrawHue.RecolorFull(hues[color], bit);
```

Is your problem.  Depending on the value you are passing, you are compounding the *hue* of the image and making it darker each time.

## Edit

I am assuming, from your description, that you are passing the same image with each iteration.  In other words, you are passing the image, changing the hue, then passing the resulting image, changing it's hue, etc.

The hue changes will have a cumulative effect.  It's not like a color change.

Good luck!

Comment: If i comment this string- there isn't color, but bitmap doesn't going darket. Mb u a right =\

Comment: But if i make:             Hues hues2 = Hues.Load(huePath);

            if (color != 0) RedrawHue.RecolorFull(hues2[color], bit); and will create each time function in a new object- it doesn't help.

Comment: How just after creating newbit it could changes everytime?

Comment: @FSou1 are you asking how repeatedly darkening the hues universally across the picture makes the picture get darker? Or do you just not understand how hues work?